# php - change value to src attribute if 'cid:' are found in html document

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, preg-match-all, src

how can I tell php to look if a src attribute starts with 'cid:' and if yes, replace it with another value?

```
<img src="cid:xx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="544" height="340">

<?php
    $new_link = "http://www.example.com'";
    preg_replace("#^cid:#", $new_link);
?>
```

Comment: at the time of the replace, do you know what the xxxx... is? if you know what that xxxx.. would be, you can just build out that `cid:xxxxxxx...` string and then use `str_replace` to replace it with the link. Regex is messy

Comment: NO the result will be always different.

Comment: The cid link is generated ith the html so the script need to look at the html and If src="cid:' are found replace them with new string. http://codepad.viper-7.com/uNaUvZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` is for the start of a string or line depending on the modifier being used. You want

```
<?php
$new_link = "http://www.example.com'";
echo preg_replace('~src="cid.*?"~',"src='$new_link'", '<img src="cid:xx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="544" height="340">');
?>
```

Output:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com'' width="544" height="340">
```

The second trailing single quote at the end of the `src` is from the `$newlink`.

The `.` is for any character `*` for any number of "any characters" and the `?` says stop at the first occurrence of the next character. In this case that is a double quote which should make this capture the whole string src attribute.

If the src can be using both single or double quotes this should account for that (also note i removed the trailing quote here from `$newlink`).

```
<?php
$new_link = "http://www.example.com";
echo preg_replace('~src=("|\')cid.*?\1~',"src='$new_link'", '<img src="cid:xx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="544" height="340">');
?>
```

Comment: thanks but it stops working using "#src="cid.*?"#". Should be this instead? "#src=cid"."*?#"

Comment: Did you try it after the edit? I had the quotes wrong at first.

Comment: ok. what about if '<img src="cid:xx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="544" height="340">' is generated and not always the same?

Comment: As long as it is always `src="cid:anythinghere"` it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79171/discussion-between-chris85-and-snos).